# Not able to print whole chart amcharts4

Tags: charts, amcharts, amcharts4

Using amcharts4
I'm using export menu and other getImage() for printing the gantt chart
But the limitation is Im only able to print the rows visible in chart
I want all rows image throughout the bottom

[referance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gynLg.png)

Here you can see only some middle rows are shown
If I try to print , this much rows will print only
Need to print whole chart

Thanks in advance